# Chrome Extension Event Listener Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a sample simple chrome extension . I need to create a event listener for button. It is not working don't know why? I tried jQuery and javascript to write event listener still not triggering. Since the log in document ready is working i think there is no issue with Manifest.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rama").click(function() {
        console.log('afawfafaf');
    });
    console.log("rambo adloaded!");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <h1>Easy </h1>
</HEAD>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    min-width: 300px;
}
</style>

<BODY>
    <button type="button" id="rama">fe!</button>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

**Manifest**

```
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",


    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "easy",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.1",
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
    ],
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "rambo.png",
        "default_popup": "easy.html"

    },
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js"]
    }

}
```

Any Idea what i am Missing ??

Comment: Your `easy.html` should contain the js for managing the dom of the browser action. Content scripts have no direct access to browser action scope.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, you don't need the content script at all in manifest.json for this task. Also, the popup is a separate page with its own URL and separate devtools which you can access by right-clicking the popup, then clicking ”inspect”.